Incorrect Syntax near ',' in SQL query execution in Spring JPA but executes successfully in database
I am using Java 8 and have an update query with 3 columns concatenated to one in the where clause. the query works perfectly in the SQL Server, but when I execute from the code, it results in Incorrect syntax error.
Query used in the code:
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE ListView SET stre_group = :streGroup, method = :mthodSelected, " +
                "alloc_schedule = :allocationSchedule " +
                "WHERE concat(job_id,':',item_nr,':',whse_nr) IN (:resultValue)", nativeQuery = true)
void updateWorklist(String streGroup, String mthodSelected,
                                    List<String> allocationSchedule ,
                                    List<String> resultValue);


DB:
UPDATE tablename  SET stre_group = 'store 4', method = 'store 4',
auto_alloc_action = 'store 4', alloc_schedule = 'store 4'
WHERE concat(job_id,':',item_nbr,':',whse_nbr) IN ('1:10:1')

I tried to check on the syntax and not finding the cause of the issue.

ERRO o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax near ','.
? ERROR 29524 i.m.ca.service.updateDataService: Error occurred while updating records: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement


FYI you can enable query logging and see what the query is.

@FedericoklezCulloca : I have enabled logging, it is printing like this:
Hibernate:
UPDATE
ListView
SET
stre_group  = ?,
method = ?,
alloc_schedule = ?
WHERE
concat(job_id,':',item_nr,':',whse_nr) IN (
?
)

item_nbr and whse_nbr are spelled differently in your SQL query then in your string where you spell them as item_nr and whse_nr.

At a glance alloc_schedule = :allocationSchedule while you are passing in a list to it: List<String> allocationSchedule so what the database is executing is not exactly what is happeing on the application.

They won't cause a SQL syntax error mind, @SledgeHammer , but still a valid point.

Your problem is happening because one of the parameters being passed to the query has a List type and in the query you are using an equals sign =. The reason it is working in the database is because you are not using the exact same parameter in the application.
Essentially this part of the query: alloc_schedule = :allocationSchedule
Because the parameter is a List<String> allocationSchedule the final query being executed will be something like:
UPDATE ...., alloc_schedule = 'store 4', 'SomeOtherValueInTheList' WHERE ...

Hence the error: SqlExceptionHelper : Incorrect syntax near ','.
So you need to fix the parameter so it is a plain String (and obviously the callers of this method)

Thanks.Fixed the parameter and working fine.
